# Is "be" always a copular verb or there are instances of it being the predicate?

Tags: syntax

Is the verb "be" in this sentence:

"I am".

copular with an implicit predicate "here" or "now" or non-copular, as the predicate of the sentence?

Comment: It could be depending on the context, e.g. A: "Are you tired"? B: "I am" (copula be") / "Are you going to the party"? B: "I am". (progressive auxiliary). Note that "be" is virtually always an auxiliary verb, even when it is the only verb in the clause. Copula "be" refers to its function as a syntactic link relating PC to S

Comment: Note that any answers to this question apply only to various theories of **English** grammar; there is no "be" in other languages that is exactly like English "be".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### "Be" can sometimes be a predicate

The verb "be" has several different meanings. The most prominent one is just as a copula, but it can also mean "to exist", as in Descartes' famous "I think, therefore I am". In this sense, it can be a predicate: try replacing it with "exist", which clearly isn't a copula, and the structure and meaning of the sentence will remain exactly the same.

The sentence in your question might be using this meaning, or might be a copula with an implicit predicate. It depends on context. (If it were preceded by "Hey, are you coming to the meeting?" for example, "I am" would be followed by an implied "...coming to the meeting". In this case, it's just an auxiliary verb.)

Comment: That's pretty much an artificial construction. Nobody but philosophers and theologians use English _be_ that way; it never occurs in questions, for instance: *_Is God?_ Mostly English speakers would use _exist_ or _be_ with some complement like _be real_. My experience in English grammar has been that it's always wiser to treat _be_ as an auxiliary, even when there's nothing else there. Oh, and Decartes didn't use _be_; he was writing French.

Comment: @jlawler It definitely feels artificial in English, but people understand it just fine. It's more common in other languages, such as the Latin Descartes originally wrote in, but since native speakers understand it I'd still consider it valid English.

Comment: Thanks. I forgot it was Latin; in that case the verb _esse_ would be quite different from English _be_, since there was plenty of inflection for it to carry, and subjects were frequently omitted.